# How to add UITapGestureRecognizer inside a UIView with the target set ```self```

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

I created a customized UIView and added a UITapGestureRecognizer inside it like this:

```
@interface CustomizedView : UIView

@property(nonatomic,strong) UILabel* label;

@end

@implementation CustomizedView
-(void) targetActionForThisView:(id)sender{
    NSLog(@"Clicked!");
}
-(void) commonInit{
    _label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,200,100)];
    _label.text = @"test string 1234";
    UITapGestureRecognizer* g = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] 
       initWithTarget:self action:@selector(targetActionForThisView:)];
    g.enabled = YES;
    [self setExclusiveTouch:YES];
    [self setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
    [self setMultipleTouchEnabled:YES];
    [_label addGestureRecognizer:g];
    [self addSubview:_label];
}
-(instancetype)init{
    self = [super init];
    [self commonInit];
    return self;
}
-(instancetype)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    [self commonInit];
    return self;
}
@end
```

Then I add it into the view controller:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    CustomizedView* aView = [[CustomizedView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,300,300)];
    [self.view addSubview:aView];
}
```

But the gesture won't work.
I know usually the target is set to the view's controller.
But why this doesn't work? And how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your code to this

```
-(void)actionViewTap:(id)sender{
    NSLog(@"Clicked!");
}
-(void) commonInit{
    _label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,200,100)];
    _label.text = @"test string 1234";
    _label.userInteractionEnabled = true;//Enable userInteractionEnabled
    UITapGestureRecognizer* g = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]
                             initWithTarget:self action:@selector(actionViewTap:)];//Here should be actionViewTap:
    g.enabled = YES; 
    [self setExclusiveTouch:YES];
    [self setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
    [self setMultipleTouchEnabled:YES];
    [_label addGestureRecognizer:g];
    [self addSubview:_label];
}
-(instancetype)init{
    self = [super init];
    [self commonInit];
    return self;
}
-(instancetype)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    [self commonInit];
    return self;
 }
```

Comment: the selector is a mistake while I gave the minimized code.Have already corrected it in my question.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the UITapGestureRecognizer object on the view you want which is the label object.

```
[_l addGestureRecognizer:g];
```

should become:

```
[_label addGestureRecognizer:g];
```

Comment: It's my mistake for my minimizing code. This is not the point but thanks anyway.